# Php site - Contact form - When sending right to left messages its received gibberish

Tags: javascript, php, html, utf-8, contact-form

I have a website most of it is written in English but since it has a contact form some users send messages in right to left languages. So I'm supporting charset=utf-8 like so in the index.php head tag like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
            <?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset=utf-8" />
```

Then I have a `contact.js` file which is a simple function to push the message and the `contact.php` file with the details and where the email body is being generated again. Below the entire code I've set `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` And then here's the contact form PHP file:

```
<?php

// configure
$from = 'contact form <website@website.com>';
$sendTo = 'contact form <contact@website.com>';
$subject = 'New Message from website.com';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message'); // array variable name => Text to appear in email
$okMessage = 'Thank you';
$errorMessage = 'Please try again';

// let's do the sending
try {
    $emailText = "The following contact has sent a Message from website.com\n\n";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo $encoded;
} else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}

?>
```

The email is sent & received in my inbox but when the message/name are written in right to left languages no matter what I tried I got gibberish.

Comment: if the right to left language is not english words, then probably you can try passing headers in mail function like $headers = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

Comment: @Khem I've tried what you suggested and it still doesn't work :(